# escape special character (%)

Tags: batch-file, escaping, character

i have a command that displays the current name of the batch file that it's code is appended to.

```
echo %~n0%~x0
```

i want to send the command to a text file without changing its syntax.
for example;

```
echo %~n0%~x0 >> somefile.txt
```

i tried escaping the percentage sign with another percentage but it doesn't work.

```
echo %%~n0%%~x0
```

any ideas...?

Comment: As `echo %%~n0%%~x0` works in a batch file as expected (outputs `%~n0%~x0`)  you should show your _minimal_ batch file where it fails. Or at least what result you get

Answer (score 1):

Try the caret instead of the %% like this ^% you might also need to escape the escape (I know weird and why .. but ..you might).

Using the CARET **^**  worked for me.

```
echo ^%%~n0^%%~x0 >> somefile.txt
```

this code will produce the batch file name
echo ^%~n0^%~x0 >> somefile.txt

Comment: The caret works only directly in command prompt; in batch files you usually need to double the `%` sign...

Comment: @aschipfl here is my code in the batch file , it works for me echo ^%%~n0^%%~x0 >> somefile.txt

Comment: You can use the caret, but it works the same way without the caret.

Comment: @zask - if the answer helped you - please mark as answer.